# VBA: repeating the same process in the next column

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to automate the calculation of RSS for different columns. In this below example, I calculate the RSS for Y values in column G. Only my Y values will be changing columns which means that my X values will always be in the same columns.

Is it possible to automatically repeat this calculation for the next column of Y values in (e.g. column H) and so on until there are no more names in the first row of a column?

I have already tried to loop this process but VBA would always give me some error message.

```
Private Sub Regr(strWksData As String, WsTools As Worksheet, strWksFF3 As String, strWksResult As String)

Dim NoOfRow As Long

Dim rX1 As Range
Dim rX2 As Range
Dim rX3 As Range

Dim rY1 As Range
Dim rY2 As Range
Dim rX3 As Range


'Set X ranges
Set rX1 = Worksheets(strWksFF3).Range("C2:E21")
Set rX2 = Worksheets(strWksFF3).Range("C22:E41")
Set rX3 = Worksheets(strWksFF3).Range("C42:E64")

'Set Y ranges
Set rY1 = Worksheets(strWksData).Range("G2:G21")
Set rY2 = Worksheets(strWksData).Range("G22:G41")
Set rY3 = Worksheets(strWksData).Range("G42:G64")

'Loop through columns
'Provide statistic
Do Until Worksheets(strWksData).Range("G").Value = ""

vStat1 = Application.WorksheetFunction.LinEst(rY1, rX1, True, True)
Worksheets(strWksResult).Range("G2").Value = vStat1(5, 2)
NoOfRow = Worksheets(strWksData).Range("G2:G21").Rows.Count
WsTools.Range("B2").Value = NoOfRow

vStat2 = Application.WorksheetFunction.LinEst(rY2, rX2, True, True)
Worksheets(strWksResult).Range("G3").Value = vStat2(5, 2)
NoOfRow = Worksheets(strWksData).Range("G22:G41").Rows.Count
WsTools.Range("B3").Value = NoOfRow

vStat3 = Application.WorksheetFunction.LinEst(rY3, rX3, True, True)
Worksheets(strWksResult).Range("G4").Value = vStat3(5, 2)
NoOfRow = Worksheets(strWksData).Range("G42:G64").Rows.Count
WsTools.Range("B4").Value = NoOfRow

Call GetNextColumn("G")
counter1 = counter1 + 1

Loop


MsgBox ("RSS Done")

End Sub
```

Any form of help would be deeply appreciated. Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Add a range argument say, `rngColvals` then use this instead of your hard coded ones, ry1.  Or enclose the provide statistic code downwards in a for next loop, with values, 0 to 1, and offset column G accordingly

Comment: How would I be able code this? I am fairly new to VBA...

Comment: `for i=0 to 1:vStat3 = Application.WorksheetFunction.LinEst(rY3.offset(0,i), rX3.offset(0,i), True, True):next i`  something like this, I'm not able to test at mo.  Look at the integral parts `offset` and `for..next loop` google/research those, you'll understand then.

Comment: Will do, thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You can get the last column index of a worksheet with the following code:

```
Dim wSheet : Set wSheet = Thisworkbook.worksheets("mysheetnamehere")
lastColumn = wSheet.Cells(1, wSheet.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
```

This will give you 25 if the last column is Y.  Then you can write a simple enough loop:

```
For myCol = 1 to lastColumn
    wSheet.Cells(2, myCol).Value = "Something"
Next myCol
```

The above example would iterate over all columns in row 2 with a header value and insert the text "Something" into them.

You can also get the last row, should you need that, with the very similar:

```
lastRow = wSheet.Cells(wSheet.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
```

Comment: Where in the above code could I incorporate this loop? I do not have much experience in coding with VBA..